# What is the cause of so many people disconnecting at the beginning?

Tags: dota-2

In nearly every game i play someone disconnects at the very beginning. Is this caused by someone leaving the game already? I would find that very hard to believe because it just happens too often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar impression for some time,but it is really just the **random** luck of matchmaking.To most of them the problem is **game crashing** since on the beggining there is a bunch of things thath needs to be pre-loaded,depending on their PCs something is about to go wrong.

For some time there was a **bug** that would often crash the game when loading certain characters,it was weird too see almost all players disconnecting and I was wandering the same thing as you are...untill it crashed on me too.

Thing is that dota 2 is still in **beta** so the crashes and bugs are expected.Before the tournament developers tried to balance the game and make it more stable,and yet it was common to see players on tournament getting disconnected.Note that they were playing on same "network" and probably high-end mainteined computers,which is usually not the case with common players.

Comment: that's pretty sad, hopefully all these bugs/crashes get worked out.  id like to play a full game without random disconnects

Comment: This game is in permanent beta

Comment: I would also add that some people will do it after character pick, if they encounter problems/lag. Ie. their game is running poorly for some reason, so they pick and quickly restart Dota2, to try to resolve the problems.